# CSS gradiant border bottom

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, border

I am stuck with something.
Using Bootstrap 5 navbar, I try to make a simple a simple 40px hight vertical border bottom, going from color #e5e5e5 to color #fefefe
Here is the sample image:

[image]

Thank you if you have a final idea because I am fighting with that without any success :(

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `border-image`

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  background: lightblue;
  border-image: 
    linear-gradient(#e5e5e5,#fefefe) 0 0 100% 0/
    0 0 40px 0/0 0 40px 0; /* adjust both 40px to control the size */
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Borders cannot have gradients (yet).

Use either a `drop-shadow` filter or a pseudo-element.

The drop-shadow *effect* is really what you are after so adjust the color as required.

**Drop-shadow**

```css
header {
  height: 75px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.filter {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 5px 5px grey)
}
```

```html
<header class="filter"></header>
```

**Pseudo-element**

```css
header {
  height: 75px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.pseudo {
  position: relative;
}

.pseudo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(#e5e5e5, #fefefe);
}
```

```html
<header class="pseudo"></header>
```

Comment: Why .pseudo:before or not .pseudo:after ?

Comment: Stacking context really but in this case force of habit.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to solve ur issue.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Add Bootstrap CSS link here -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .custom-navbar {
      position: relative;
    }

    .navbar-border {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #e5e5e5, #fefefe);
      content: "";
      z-index: -1;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light custom-navbar">
  <!-- Your navbar content goes here -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your Logo</a>
    <!-- Add other navbar elements as needed -->
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-border"></div> <!-- This div creates the border -->
</nav>

<!-- Add Bootstrap JS and Popper.js scripts here -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
```